# Music app ignores the "stop" time option

Tags: itunes, music, ventura

The Music app (formerly iTunes) has an option where you can set the "stop" time of a song (so for example you could skip some dead silence time at the end of a song).  I think this used to work in the past, but doesn't work now for me (Ventura 13.3.1, Music 1.3.4.56)

For example, I have a song whose length is 7:18 but the last 25 seconds are just crowd noise.  I did "Get Options" -> "Options" and set "Stop" to 6:55, with the check mark on.  When the song plays, it displays 6:55 as the end time but keeps playing past it, with the time indicator showing 6:55, for the remaining 23 seconds.

Can anyone say if they also see this bug?  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: To be clear this refers to an mp3 file on my computer, not to a song from the cloud.